# How to Parse a C# 2D Array in a ViewBag to a javascript 2D Array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, google-visualization

I pass a C# 2D Array in a ViewBag to my View and I would like to parse it in a Javascript 2D array to use it as a source for a google chart. I have tried:

```
 var tab = @Html.Raw(@ViewData["tabComplet"]);
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tab);
```

But it doesn't work, does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass C# ASP.NET array to Javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-sharp-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array)

Comment: or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023972/assign-c-sharp-string-of-array-or-string-to-javascript-array), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942385/pass-c-sharp-array-to-javascript), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155107/looping-through-values-from-c-sharp-array-using-javascript)...

Comment: Nothing, it shows me an error "Unexpected token ," in a jquery file so it means that the array is not valid to be used as a source of a google chart

Comment: That is what your console says, your HTML source (View Source) will show something, even if it is not valid javascript

Comment: By the way, `ViewBag` and `ViewData` are [not the same thing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem)

Comment: Yes I Know, thanks for the links, will try to find out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Find whole project on [GitHub](https://github.com/foyzulkarim/Google-Chart) or watch the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEYpvDF6qy8ZlocRog_kqeTWkUag-p4XV)

In controller, add the following code

```
            // prepare a 2d array in c#
            ArrayList header = new ArrayList { "Task Name", "Hours"};
            ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList {"Work", 2};
            ArrayList data2 = new ArrayList { "Eat", 2 };
            ArrayList data3 = new ArrayList { "Sleep", 2 };
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList {header, data1, data2, data3};
            // convert it in json
            string dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None);
            // store it in viewdata/ viewbag
            ViewBag.Data = new HtmlString(dataStr);
```

In _Layout.cshtml, add the Google script

```
@*google chart*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">   </script>
```

And at last, in the view add the below code

```
<script>    
    var data = JSON.parse('@ViewBag.Data');
    console.log(data);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

        var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(chartData, options);
    }
</script>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

i will show chart in there. but the data will come from viewdata instead of calling jQuery Ajax request.
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```